# How do I attach an ethernet dongle to a Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-zero

I connect the Ethernet to micro USB dongle to the USB port of the Zero.  I then connect a micro USB to USB dongle to the PWR port.  However, I still don't see any signs that the device is on the network (I checked the list of attached devices on my router).

I've tested all parts in isolation and they all work.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Is this USB-Ethernet-Dongle supported by Raspbian? What does `lsusb` and `ifconfig` tell you?

Comment: @kwasmich How would I check `lsusb` and `ifconfig`?  I have no way to connect to the Zero (since all ports are taken).

Comment: @kwasmich I can't seem to find a list of supported USB-Ethernet dongles.  Do you have a URL handy?

Comment: There is no definitive list of supported devices only a community based collection of devices known to work or not at [eLinux](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Ethernet_adapters).

Comment: You can use an USB hub to connect up a keyboard along with your dongle and hook up a display via HDMI. That would be the easiest. Also you can connect a USB-Serial adapter to the RX and TX pins of the GPIO. Either way you will gain access to your Pi and can execute the above commands.

Comment: @kwasmich That's a lot of hardware to buy.  I think it might be cheaper to get a Zero W at this point.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not go with a Raspberry Pi with built-in Ethernet?

Comment: @kwasmich I need the small form factor and very low power draw.

Comment: Yes but you can use a full featured Pi for development and then just swap the SD-Card. That's the magic behind Raspberry Pi. I'd recommend you to go with a [USB-Serial](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/b5f0RvOp) converter which you can get pretty cheap.

Comment: @kwasmich I have a large RPi.  I am just trying to get this network dongle to work on the Zero.

Comment: Does the dongle work on the large Pi? And what does `lsusb` and `ifconfig` give you as output when you try it there?

Comment: I can't test it.  The large RPi doesn't have a microUSB port (other than power) and I don't have a microUSB to regular USB dongle.

Comment: Then you might need one of [these](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/c9iia0jJ).